# Twitterizer Search By First and Last Name

Tags: c#, search, twitter, twitterizer

I'm using the following function to search in Twitter with Twitterizer

```
TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> searchResponse = TwitterSearch.Search(query);
```

This function doesn't work well with First+Last Name only with user name.
is there any other way to perform this search with the basic details and not the screen name?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'd need [users/search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/search) to look up the users, get their screen names, and pass thàt to the search API.

As far as I know, there's no way to directly search for full names.